# How to pass a variable to SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to programming and have been following a tutorial. To this point my WPF application has been calling a simple "get all" stored procedure, just to get something working, and now it does. But in my application, I want to be able to pass a `FeedGroupId` as an input variable to this stored procedure (`FeedGroupId` is taken from a combobox selection) so that it will return only the pens that have that `FeedGroupId`.

EndPoint:

```
public async Task<List<FeedGroupPenModel>> GetPensByFeedGroupId(int FeedGroupId)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _apiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync($"/api/FeedGroup/GetPensByFeedGroupId/{FeedGroupId}"))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<FeedGroupPenModel>>();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFeedGroupPens_GetPensByFeedGroupId]
    @FeedGroupId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        li.FeedGroupId, li.PenId, li.AsFedPounds, 
        f.RationId, p.PenName           
    FROM
        LotInfo AS li
    INNER JOIN
        FeedGroups AS f ON li.FeedGroupId = f.FeedGroupId
    INNER JOIN
        PenInfo AS p ON li.PenId = p.Id
    WHERE
        li.FeedGroupId = @FeedGroupId
END
```

Data access API:

```
public List<FeedGroupPenModel> GetPensByFeedGroupId(int FeedGroupId)
{
    var output = _sql.LoadData<FeedGroupPenModel, dynamic>("dbo.spFeedGroupPens_GetPensByFeedGroupId", new { FeedGroupId } , "The.....Data");

    return output;
}
```

API Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("GetPensByFeedGroupId/{FeedGroupId:int}")]
    [Route("GetPensByFeedGroupId")]
    public List<FeedGroupPenModel> GetByFeedGroupId(int FeedGroupId)        
    {
        int feedGroupId = FeedGroupId;
        return _feedGroupPenData.GetPensByFeedGroupId(feedGroupId);
    }
```

Comment: *"I've seen other questions on StackOverflow that pertain to this topic, but I haven't found anything that looks like what (I think) I'm needing here"* - If you don't tell us what those questions are and why they didn't help, you're likely to get the same information, which doesn't help anyone. You haven't shown the stored procedure or anything related to calling it, so I'm not sure what kind of help you're expecting.

Comment: @madreflection  I've added the stored procedure I'm wanting to use to the question. As far as "other questions"...the ones I'm seeing are about passing arrays or nulls to a stored procedure and I didn't think they really applied to my case here.

Comment: And how are you trying to call it? There's a gap between requesting `/api/FeedGroup/GetPens` and calling `spFeedGroupPens_GetPensByFeedGroupId`. Dig deeper. I imagine the answer is there for you and, if not, at least the scope at which you need to focus will be more apparent.

Comment: @madreflection I should have clarified. This is the new stored procedure I'm wanting to call. So 'GetPens' will be replaced with 'GetPensByFeedGroupId' in the EndPoint. I'll update the EndPoint and ViewModel in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: First, you need to pass the `@FeedGroupId` parameter. Without knowing *how* you're calling stored procedures, there's not enough information here. Then that layer needs the value from the layer above it, and then from the layer above that, and so on until the web API method, and then the call to that endpoint needs to include the value. This is too broad for one question. Start with just calling the stored procedure. Remove everything else from the question.

Comment: I already have it that far. When I called the `GetPens` stored procedure by selecting the `FeedGroup` name from the ComboBox, it returns ALL the pens...everything worked like its supposed to. Simply put, the `GetPensByFeedGroupId` is the exact same procedure, just with the added `@FeedGroupId` parameter so it only returns SOME of the pens. I can add the Controller from the API if that would help.

Comment: The only code of interest is the code which calls the SP - and I can't see it?

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something...My EndPoint calls the stored procedure. All pertinent code from my WPF app is here for calling this stored procedure. In my understanding, the parameter goes(should go) from the ComboBox, to the ViewModel, to the EndPoint, to the API. The ViewModel calls the Endpoint and when it gets a SuccessStatusCode it in turn calls `"/api/FeedGroup/GetPensByFeedGroupId"`.

Comment: The WPF app itself is not pertinent, except perhaps for how you call the endpoint, so all that stuff about the combo box and and the view model is noise. You have an ID, you want to query something with that. The endpoint code is what's relevant and you haven't shown it. If your endpoint is calling the stored procedure directly, I would expect to see a `SqlConnection` and maybe a `SqlCommand` or a Dapper query method somewhere in there.

Comment: @madreflection. Your last comment helps! I've had in mind my problem was in my WPF app. I've added code from my DataAccess file of my API to the question. Could that what your looking for?

Comment: Please remove the stuff that I said was noise. We're kind of getting there. It *looks* like it could work. Have you unit-tested it? Have you stepped through it? By the way, your parameter `int @FeedGroupId` doesn't need the `@` symbol. That's only needed when an identifier you want to use is a keyword, and "FeedGroupId" is not a keyword.

Comment: Ok, I've simplified my question a bit. I have walked through it. When I debug now, my parameter gets through...until the API controller, where the value has changed to 0. If I manually change it back through the debugger, then it works and displays the correct data.

Comment: Be careful how you describe it, because it matters in how you think about the problem. Was it "changed to 0" or "never assigned a value so it has the default of 0"? I'm going to assert that it's the latter, since your API call doesn't pass the FeedGroupId (e.g. `?FeedGroupId=xxxx`, where xxxx is the value retrieved from the combo box).

Comment: OK, yes, I would agree that the value was never set in the API. So why isn't `FeedGroupId` being passed from the EndPoint to the API Controller?

Comment: Because you're not sending it in the request. You don't use the parameter anywhere. The only place "FeedGroupId" appears in `GetPensByFeedGroupId` is at the end of the resource path, `/api/FeedGroup/GetPensByFeedGroupId`, but that's the name of the endpoint. It doesn't include the value to give to the stored procedure.

Comment: Well, that sounds like that is the answer to my question then! If you'd show me what needs to happen in an answer I'd give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My controller I specified the argument as part of the url: `[HttpGet("GetPensByFeedGroupId/{FeedGroupId:int}")]` In the endpoint I passed the argumented as part of the url: `.GetAsync($"/api/FeedGroup/GetPensByFeedGroupId/{FeedGroupId}")` I don't know if this was the best way, but the code works now. My Question has been updated to reflect this.